# PhpStorm Line between html open and close tag

Tags: phpstorm, settings

I have updated PhpStorm, and thin lines between html open/close tag just appeared.

Where can I disabled them ?

[image: click to see screen capture of those lines]

Answer (score 3):

In **File | Settings | Editor | General | Appearance**, disable **Show indent guides**

[image]